# Verifying transport equation solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have just started PDE's and I have the transport equation

$u_t + au_x = 0$

which has the general solution

$u(x,t) = f(x - at)$

In a book I'm reading it says this can be verified by substitution as follows

$u_t + au_x = -a f'(x - at) + af'(x - at) = 0$

What I don't get is the $f'$'s. The first one was differentiated w.r.t to t and the second one was differentiated w.r.t. x so I don't see how you can automatically say that they are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $v(x,t) = x - at$. Then $u = f(v(x,t))$ and by the chain rule, $$u_t = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{df}{dv}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = f'(v)(-a) = -af'(x - at)$$ Similarly for $u_x$.